# TakeWhile using query syntax

Tags: c#, linq

Having

```
public static IEnumerable<long> FibonacciNumbers() {
 long current = 0;
 long next = 1;

 while (true) {
  long previous = current;
  current = next ;
  next = previous + next;
  yield return current;
 }
}
```

I can get the first fibonacci numbers less that 100 with

```
var series = FibonacciNumbers().TakeWhile(num => num < 100);
```

Just being curious, how would I do that using query syntax ?

Comment: Wow - I posted this to my blog only eight hours ago: http://madprops.org/blog/while-link-keyword/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wouldn't - there's nothing in C# query expressions that corresponds to `TakeWhile` (or Take, Skip, SkipWhile etc). C# query expressions are *relatively* limited, but cover the biggies:

- Select (via `select` and `let`)
- Where (via `where`)
- SelectMany (via secondary `from` clauses)
- OrderBy/ThenBy (and descending) (via `orderby` clauses)
- Join (via `join` clauses)
- GroupBy (via `groupby` clauses)
- GroupJoin (via `join ... into` clauses)

[VB 9's query support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364068(VS.80).aspx#vb9overview_topic7) is a bit more extensive, but personally I like C#'s approach - it keeps the *language* relatively simple, but you can still do everything you want via dot notation.

Comment: Also I don't think while fits into a query expression... it is easily confused with a regular "imperative" while construct.

Comment: I personally don't like the C# approach but I agree with you. I don't like making the language look like FoxPro. I wish C# did not have that syntax at all (I agree it sometimes looks better).

Comment: @Skurmedel: TakeWhile is in VB9's query support; I don't think it's really *bad*, but not particularly necessary. @Mehrdad: I like it for joins and anywhere that transparent identifiers are introduced. In fact, I've got a new section in C# in Depth 2nd edition discussing pros and cons :)

Comment: Hehe, let's say my general opinion on VBs syntax is not of the positive kind.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in syntax for this in LINQ. Besides, writing it in LINQ would be more verbose and wouldn't really aid clarity, so there's no real need in this case.

<strike>Also, you should use `Take` rather than `TakeWhile` here.</strike>

Comment: -1 for suggesting using Take. The point of using TakeWhile is to keep going until he reaches a Fibonacci number greater than or equal to 100. He can't predict how many elements that will be (without prior knowledge of the Fibonacci sequence). TakeWhile is exactly what's required.

Comment: My bad – I misread it as trying to take the first 100 Fibonacci numbers.